# Android ANR when bind application provider

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

I'm having a very hard time debugging an Android ANR problem.

This is what I get from Google Play Console - Android vitals (released version from Google Play):

Android 10:

```
  at libcore.io.Linux.access (Native method)
  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access (ForwardingOs.java:73)
  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.access (BlockGuardOs.java:71)
  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access (ForwardingOs.java:73)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.access (ActivityThread.java:7308)
  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess (UnixFileSystem.java:281)
  at java.io.File.exists (File.java:815)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.ensureExternalDirsExistOrFilter (ContextImpl.java:2670)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDirs (ContextImpl.java:709)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalFilesDirs (ContextWrapper.java:258)
  at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs (ContextCompat.java:381)
  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy (FileProvider.java:691)
  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy (FileProvider.java:635)
  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.attachInfo (FileProvider.java:416)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:7045)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6590)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6485)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:225)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1865)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:359)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7418)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Android 11:

```
  at libcore.io.Linux.access (Native method)
  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access (ForwardingOs.java:72)
  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.access (BlockGuardOs.java:73)
  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.access (ForwardingOs.java:72)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.access (ActivityThread.java:7639)
  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess (UnixFileSystem.java:281)
  at java.io.File.exists (File.java:815)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.ensureExternalDirsExistOrFilter (ContextImpl.java:2991)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDirs (ContextImpl.java:768)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalFilesDirs (ContextWrapper.java:278)
  at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api19Impl.getExternalFilesDirs (ContextCompat.java:845)
  at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs (ContextCompat.java:406)
  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy (FileProvider.java:691)
  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy (FileProvider.java:635)
  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.attachInfo (FileProvider.java:416)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:7341)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:6882)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6793)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 (ActivityThread.java:250)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1973)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:250)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7766)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:604)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

There is I/O operation (can take a lot of time), I understand, but how can I solve it? There is no code from my app. Does anyone know what can usually cause these ANRs? Thank you!

Comment: Having the same issue. Do you finally find a reason/solution?

Comment: Hello @JérémyReynaud: no yet

Comment: I am, catch same issue with init FileProvider while startup app.

Comment: Any suggestion for this ANR?